# what do i need to send input type via. submit button please

Tags: php, email, submit

i would like to make a code of php to submit some informations to send to my private email address the code i'm looking for is to send  via e-mail and submit. = this is my code:

```
"<div class="form_settings">
            <p><span>Navn</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_name" value="" /></p>
            <p><span>Email Addresse</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="" /></p>
            <p><span>Besked</span><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="5" cols="50" name="your_message"></textarea></p>
            <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="send"></p>
          </div>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this on the page where your form action points to (e.g. if you have  then you should put this code on send_message.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['your_name']) && isset($_POST['your_email']) && isset($_POST['your_message'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['your_name']) && !empty($_POST['your_email']) && isset($_POST['your_message'])) {
            $to = "INSERT THE EMAIL ADDRESS YOU WANT TO SEND TO";
            $subject = "SUBJECT";
            $name = $_POST['your_name'];
            $email = $_POST['your_email'];
            $message = "$name sent you a message:"
            $message .= "<br><br>" . $_POST['your_message'];
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";

            if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
                header('Location: confirmation.php');
            };
        };
    };
?>
```

P.S. Learning PHP takes time but is worth it, youtube has lots of good videos.

Comment: i'm sorta new to php, but it's nice to have some help.Thank you for your time to reply to my question, if i would make an alert for the user to know that the mail got sent, what could i do?

Comment: You could use a different page (e.g. use action="confirmation.php" in the <form> element.

On that page you could then add a message saying sent successfully.

Comment: Or alternatively you could change this:

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

to this:

    if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
        header('Location: confirmation.php');
    };

This is better than the other one I wrote as it only redirects if the mail was sent successfully (mail() returns true if it works).

Comment: I'll edit the answer to show this.